# defining a partial geostationary projection with matplotlib Basemap

Tags: python, matplotlib, geos, matplotlib-basemap

i'm having trouble creating a custom geostationary projection with Basemap. what i'd need is not a full globe projection, but the upper third of a full disc (full width, one third from the top down ). i found an example here:

http://matplotlib.org/basemap/users/geos.html

explaining how to make a projection for the upper right quadrant of the disc using the llcrnrx, llcrnry, urcrnrx, and urcrnry keywords. following the example, i thought i would get my result like this:

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

lon_0 = 9.5
fig = plt.figure()
m1 = Basemap(projection='geos',lon_0=lon_0,resolution=None)
m = Basemap(projection='geos',lon_0=lon_0,resolution='l',
            # lower left
            llcrnrx=0., llcrnry=0.,
            # calculate the upper right coordinates, full width
            # two 3rds of the height
            urcrnrx=m1.urcrnrx, urcrnry=m1.urcrnry-m1.urcrnry/3.)

m.drawcoastlines()
plt.show()
```

which gives me a weird plot. from the example i though that for the new projection the lower left corner is always (0,0), then you just calculate the width and height coordinates (upper right). this obviously is not the case. with just bare experimentation i have this now:

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

lon_0 = 9.5
fig = plt.figure()
m1 = Basemap(projection='geos',lon_0=lon_0,resolution=None)
m = Basemap(projection='geos',lon_0=lon_0,resolution='l',
            llcrnrx=-m1.urcrnrx/2., llcrnry=m1.urcrnry/4.,
            urcrnrx=m1.urcrnrx/2., urcrnry=m1.urcrnry/2.)

m.drawcoastlines()
plt.show()
```

which gives me a rough estimate on what i'm after, but i have no idea why this works and what the corner points really represent.

i hope you guys get the drift...